# How to reduce Compile Module and Evaluate Module times?

Tags: javascript, performance

Lets use this website as an example https://contra.com/gajus

If you use Lighthouse to analyze it's performance, you will find that between Compile Module and Evaluate Module, the application is idle for about ~400ms.

Here is an example:

[image]

If my understanding behind the both concepts is correct, there are really only two things that we can do:

- Reduce how much JavaScript we load [compile module time]; and
- Reduce side-effects [evaluate module time]

Are these my two options?

As a side-note, I am surprised that CPU is not particularly busy during this timeframe. I would suspect that it is mostly CPU that is doing job then.

Comment: What is that `Task` between them?

Comment: Not sure. Lighthouse does not provide any context about it.